# Sidekiq worker crashes because Postgresql adapter not connecting on heroku

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, sidekiq

After some changes to my User model and tinkering with sidekiq workers. I'm getting this crash. Error message is below, along with the relevant worker.

It crashes whenever this worker is called:

```
'class SomeWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidetiq::Schedulable

  sidekiq_options :queue => :default



    sidekiq_options retry: false #if fails, don't resent (multiple texts)


  recurrence { hourly.minute_of_hour(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10,
                                    12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30,
                                    32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50,
                                    52, 54, 56, 58) } #set explicitly because of ice-cube sluggishness


  def perform(*args)

    account_sid = ENV['TW_ACCOUNT_SID']
    auth_token = ENV['TW_AUTH_TOKEN']

    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

    User.where(subscribed: true).find_each do |user|

       puts user.phone
    end
  end #end perform method'
```

Strangely, it doesn't crash when I go through a sinatra route that runs the same expression:

```
get '/debug' do
    User.where(subscribed: true).find_each do |user|

        puts user.phone
    end
end
```

Somehow, the worker has trouble with this, but the route doesn't.

Here's the error:

```
    2015-06-27T03:40:14.217201+00:00 app[web.1]: 6 TID-oqvhxe3ck WARN: PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217204+00:00 app[web.1]:    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217206+00:00 app[web.1]:    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217208+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217306+00:00 app[web.1]: 6 TID-oqvhxe3ck WARN: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217309+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217311+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217313+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217315+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217316+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217318+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217319+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217321+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217322+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217324+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217326+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217329+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217331+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217332+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217334+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:567:in `retrieve_connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217335+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217337+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217339+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:155:in `quoted_table_name'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217340+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:48:in `quoted_table_name'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217342+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:135:in `batch_order'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217343+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:116:in `find_in_batches'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217345+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:50:in `find_each'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217346+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/workers/some_worker.rb:104:in `perform'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217348+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:75:in `execute_job'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217349+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in process'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217350+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127:in `block in invoke'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217362+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidetiq-0.6.3/lib/sidetiq/middleware/history.rb:17:in `call_with_sidetiq_history'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217364+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidetiq-0.6.3/lib/sidetiq/middleware/history.rb:6:in `call'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217365+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217367+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:in `call'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217368+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217369+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:74:in `call'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217371+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217852+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:15:in `block in call'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217855+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:30:in `with_context'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217865+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in `call'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217867+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217868+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:132:in `call'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217870+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:132:in `invoke'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217871+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:51:in `block in process'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217873+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:98:in `stats'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217874+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:50:in `process'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217876+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `public_send'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217877+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `dispatch'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217879+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:122:in `dispatch'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217880+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:60:in `block in invoke'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217882+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:71:in `block in task'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217883+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:357:in `block in task'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217884+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:57:in `block in initialize'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.217886+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:15:in `block in create'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218173+00:00 app[web.1]: 6 TID-oqvhxe3ck ERROR: Actor crashed!
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218176+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218178+00:00 app[web.1]:    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218196+00:00 app[web.1]:    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218198+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218199+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218201+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218202+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218203+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218204+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218207+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218208+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218210+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218212+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218213+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218215+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218216+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218218+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218219+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218221+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218222+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:567:in `retrieve_connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218224+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218225+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218227+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:155:in `quoted_table_name'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218228+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:48:in `quoted_table_name'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218229+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:135:in `batch_order'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218231+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:116:in `find_in_batches'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218232+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:50:in `find_each'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218233+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/workers/some_worker.rb:104:in `perform'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218235+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:75:in `execute_job'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218236+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in process'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218237+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127:in `block in invoke'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218238+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidetiq-0.6.3/lib/sidetiq/middleware/history.rb:17:in `call_with_sidetiq_history'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218240+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidetiq-0.6.3/lib/sidetiq/middleware/history.rb:6:in `call'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218243+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218244+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:in `call'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218246+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218283+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:74:in `call'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218285+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218286+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:15:in `block in call'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218288+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:30:in `with_context'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218289+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in `call'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218290+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218292+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:132:in `call'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218293+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:132:in `invoke'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218295+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:51:in `block in process'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218297+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:98:in `stats'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218298+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sidekiq-3.4.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:50:in `process'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218299+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `public_send'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218302+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:26:in `dispatch'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218303+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:122:in `dispatch'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218305+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:60:in `block in invoke'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218306+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:71:in `block in task'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218308+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:357:in `block in task'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218310+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:57:in `block in initialize'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218311+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:15:in `block in create'
2015-06-27T03:41:29.023764+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=www.joinstorytime.org request_id=f677a593-84fa-4900-933d-8101af622fa2 fwd="54.247.188.179" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=246
2015-06-27T03:41:29.020335+00:00 app[web.1]: 54.247.188.179 - - [27/Jun/2015:03:41:29 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 477 0.0014
^[[A^[[A2015-06-27T03:42:00.424498+00:00 app[web.1]: 6 TID-oqvhx3gk0 DEBUG: [Sidetiq] Lock: sidetiq:SomeWorker:lock
2015-06-27T03:42:00.443328+00:00 app[web.1]: 6 TID-oqvhx3gk0 DEBUG: [Sidetiq] Unlock: sidetiq:SomeWorker:lock
2015-06-27T03:42:00.430315+00:00 app[web.1]: 6 TID-oqvhx3gk0 INFO: [Sidetiq] Enqueue: SomeWorker (at: 1435376640.0) (last: 1435376520.0)
2015-06-27T03:42:01.432976+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=HEAD path="/" host=www.joinstorytime.org request_id=1b8f065a-20cb-4387-b97c-c24410f30908 fwd="54.251.34.67" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=246
2015-06-27T03:42:01.441545+00:00 app[web.1]: 54.251.34.67 - - [27/Jun/2015:03:42:01 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 477 0.0125
le/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:60:in `block in invoke'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218306+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/cell.rb:71:in `block in task'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218308+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:357:in `block in task'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218310+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:57:in `block in initialize'
2015-06-27T03:40:14.218311+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/celluloid-0.16.0/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:15:in `block in create
```

Comment: You could trim down the example code a bit, making it easier to find solution: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Good point. I shortened the code example to the relevant User batching call that crashes things.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need `-e production` in your Procfile.

Comment: Yup, it turned out to be environment related. I had a condition in a helper file that checked whether RACK_ENV was test--- but I fat-fingered an assignment statement instead.